# Alamofire Authentication Using Old Credentials

Tags: ios, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to sign into my app. The username and password come from text fields. I can sign in fine but if I sign out and return to the log in screen each subsequent log in attempt uses the original credentials. For example, if I enter 'test@test.com' and 'password', I can get in but then if I sign out and enter 'test2@test.com' and 'test2password', it uses the first credentials for 'test@test.com'. Also, if I enter incorrect credentials, it will always say they incorrect even after I enter the correct credentials. The only way to get it to accept a different set of credentials is to force close the app and reopen it. The other part of this is that each subsequent call to other endpoints after the sign in requires user credentials. That all works fine once I sign in, but when I fix the log in issue by using an authorization header and not the Alamofire authenticate method, my subsequent calls don't work.

Here is how I'm trying to sign in so all of my subsequent calls work but this causes the first set of credentials to be used every time until I force close the app.

```
Alamofire.request("https://example.com/signin/", method: .get).authenticate(user: userName, password: password).responseJSON { response in
                if response.result.value != nil {
                    let results = response.result.value as? [[String: AnyObject]]
                    if results!.count > 0 {
                        if let dictionary = results?[0] {
                            if let userEmail = dictionary["email"] {
                                print("Signed in with: \(userEmail)")
                                sharedUser.userJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                                sharedUser.userEmail = self.usernameField.text!
                                sharedUser.userPassword = self.passwordField.text!
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "signInSegue", sender: nil)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            let failedSignInAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Invalid Email or Password", message: "The information you entered is incorrect. Please verify you have the correct information and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let failedAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { (action) in
                                let cookieStorage = HTTPCookieStorage.shared
                                for cookie in cookieStorage.cookies! {
                                    cookieStorage.deleteCookie(cookie)
                                }
                                let urlCache = URLCache.shared
                                urlCache.removeAllCachedResponses()
                                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                            })
                            failedSignInAlert.addAction(failedAction)
                            self.present(failedSignInAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    print("SIGN IN FAILED!")
                }

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
                    self.signInButton.isEnabled = true
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `.authenticate` uses a `URLCredential.Storage` value of `.forSession`, which means that the credential will be used for all auth challenges in a session automatically, and Alamofire doesn't get a chance to provide it's new `URLCredential`. Passing the value of `.none` may fix your issue.

```swift
.authenticate(user: userName, password: password, persistence: .none)
```